# Translate assembly to c code

Tags: c, assembly

I have the following function in assembly, but I need it in C. The code is:

```
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
add eax, 1667940388
pop ebp
ret
```

Could anybody translate this into C for me. Thanks.

Comment: homework? what did you do so far?

Comment: I literally don't know assembly thats why I'm asking. Trying to learn as I go but its for intro CTF. Just want to make sure I'm on the right track understanding everything.

Comment: Then post what you think it means, we can help you understand if you're on the right track.

Comment: @DaleLakes take a look at CSAPP. it tells a lot.

Comment: So far I know eax is a 32-bit integer representation of ebp (I think). Then you add that number and eax together. What gets returned though?

Comment: C calling convention (on x86) is such that a function's return value is stored in `eax`.

Comment: Oh ok got it. Thanks for the help guys. Gonna try to get the basics of assembly down by the end of the day since this is an obvious hole in my knowledge of computers haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the silly mistake on the `eax` return value ... its' fixed now ... my assembly is a little rusty :)

```
int function(int value) 
{
    return value + 1667940388;
}
```

Comment: it actually returns the value (in eax)

Comment: it's not correct. `eax` is return register. it return a value.

Comment: Ok that's what I was thinking. What does the ebp+8 do? Thats the only part I don't get.

Comment: The function's argument was pushed on the stack by the caller, then the function's return address. The function then pushes `ebp` on the stack then sets `ebp` to the current stack pointer. By that point, `ebp+8` points to the function's argument (`ebp+0` is the saved `ebp` value, `ebp+4` is the return address) - this being 32-bit code of course.

Comment: Ok. So if I have 2 variables in the function's argument, then ebp+8 would be the first argument and ebp+12 would be the second?

Comment: Yes, with either `cdecl` and `stdcall` calling conventions, that would be right.